# Upsert throws Missing Argument exception. Any thoughts please?

Tags: exception, dml, upsert

I tried to upsert and my code is below. But i am getting an exception and nothing is inserted or updated. Any thoughts please.

```
if(lstp.size()>0) {
    Boolean isUpsertfirstTime = true;

    try {
        upsert lstp Customer_Number__c;
    }catch (DMLException e) {
        System.debug('Re-trying');
        if(isUpsertfirstTime){
            upsert lstp Customer_Number__c;
            isUpsertfirstTime = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Customer_Number__c is an external id and unique.

**Exception:**

> Upsert failed. First exception on row 11; first error:
>   MISSING_ARGUMENT, Customer_Number__c not specified: []

Comment: Do you have security access to Customer_Number__c?

Comment: Thanks DavinC. Yes. it works when i simply give upsert lstp; only.

Comment: i am using free dev edition and logged in as sys admin

Comment: you have checked that Customer_Number__c is not null right?

Comment: Even sys. admins need to have field level access to the field @Baskaran S.

Comment: @TimChadwick if the field is null on a record, not record should then be inserted right?

Comment: the external id field will always contains data

Comment: Set to be unique if the string or id passed is null or empty String the validation would fire. But it wouldn't say the above error

Comment: @TimChadwick it is unique. And the data is customer master data from SAP and customer number does not contain null or empty.

Comment: i am using postman client to test this REST service

Comment: @Bforce: Did you find a solution to this problem. I am facing the same issue, although the field is not null, still getting missing argument error.